# I seem to be using a variable before it is fully created in Javascript, but this works -- why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

Could someone explain this to me?

```
var diagramImage = new Kinetic.Shape(function () {
    var context = this.getContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    //This is crazy tricks. It's part of the KineticJS demo website, but how am I able to assign diagramImage.color here?
    context.strokeStyle = diagramImage.color;

    var lastVertice = polygon.Vertices[polygon.Vertices.length - 1];

    context.moveTo(lastVertice.X, lastVertice.Y);

    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.Vertices.length; i++) {
        var vertice = polygon.Vertices[i];
        context.lineTo(vertice.X, vertice.Y);
    }

    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
});
```

It seems to me that `diagramImage` does not exist until the Kinetic constructor returns, but I am able (and seem to need to) assign context's `strokeStyle` to `diagramImage`'s color -- before `diagramImage` has been created? Why does this work?

EDIT: Full code:

```
function DrawPolygon(diagramLayer, polygon) {
    var diagramImage = new Kinetic.Shape(function () {
        var context = this.getContext();
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        //This is crazy tricks. It's part of the KineticJS demo website, but how am I able to assign diagramImage.color here?
        context.strokeStyle = diagramImage.color;

        var lastVertice = polygon.Vertices[polygon.Vertices.length - 1];

        context.moveTo(lastVertice.X, lastVertice.Y);

        for (var i = 0; i < polygon.Vertices.length; i++) {
            var vertice = polygon.Vertices[i];
            context.lineTo(vertice.X, vertice.Y);
        }

        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    });

    diagramImage.color = "red";

    diagramImage.on("mouseover", function () {
        this.color = "green";
        diagramLayer.draw();
    });

    diagramImage.on("mouseout", function () {
        this.color = "red";
        diagramLayer.draw();
    });

    diagramLayer.add(diagramImage);
    planViewStage.add(diagramLayer);
}
```

Comment: Is `diagramImage` already defined before this portion of code that you included?

Comment: No. See this tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-interactive-flower/ They do the same thing with the variable 'center'

Comment: Do you have additional code that you can post that proves your assertions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because where you are calling `diagramImage.color` is within a closure / function that is passed in to the `Kinetic.Shape` constructor.  This function is not called / is not executed by the constructor until after the new instance created by the constructor is assigned to `diagramImage`.

Here's a minimal example that may better explain what's happening:

```
var MyObject = function(f){
  this.myFunc = f; // f is executed sometime later...
};
MyObject.prototype.execute = function(){
  this.myFunc();
};

var myObjInst = new MyObject(function(){
  console.log("myObjInst:", myObjInst);
});
myObjInst.execute();
```

As Twisol noted, this can be improved by using `this` instead.  For example:

```
(function(){
  var MyObject = function(f){
    this.myFunc = f; // f is executed sometime later...
  };
  MyObject.prototype.execute = function(){
    this.myFunc();
  };

  var myObjInst = new MyObject(function(){
    console.log("myObjInst:", this);
  });
  myObjInst.execute();
})();
```

However, as Chris noted, unless documented by the API - there is no guarantee that `this` will refer to `Kinetic.Shape` during the callback - so continuing to use `diagramImage` here may still be the better of these 2 options.

In short, I think this is not the best API / example / use of JavaScript - and I would not consider this a nuance of JavaScript that you should have to deal with.  Sure, these nuances are there if you need them - but you don't have to.

Comment: Is there any way I can make this code more... intuitive? Or is this a nuance of Javascript that I will have to learn to love? :)

Comment: Source (literally) [here](http://www.kineticjs.com/download/kinetic-v3.7.3.js). `drawFunc` is called neither in `Kinetic.Shape` nor `Kinetic.Node`, but the fact that it's called `drawFunc` and kept as a property is telling.

Comment: @SeanAnderson: Yes, use `this` in the function instead of `diagramImage`. That's okay to do here because where `drawFunc` *is* called, it provides the right object as `this`.

Comment: @ziesemer: Your first example prints `myObjInst: undefined` as well for me. In both cases, you're calling the provided method from the constructor, which is not what Kinetic.js does - it stores it for later.

Comment: @Twisol - Sorry, I over-simplified my example.  Answer adjusted to reflect this.

Comment: @ziesemer: But now both examples work perfectly well! At the time `myFunc` is called, `myObjInst` has been assigned to and *is within `myFunc`'s scope of closure*.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that this is a 'nuance' that you shouldn't have to deal with. Capturing variables for use in a closure is normal, idiomatic Javascript. Unless you're guaranteed by the lib's API that `this` == the `Kinetic.Shape` instance during the invocation of the callback, then referring to `diagramImage` when you really mean `diagramImage` very much is the better thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting construct. What's happening appears to be:

- `diagramImage` is a reference before it's assigned anything just by virtue of the declaration. To visualize this, imagine that `var diagramImage` was on the previous line by its self.
- `Kinetic.Shape` takes a callback, that anonymous function, as one of its constructor arguments to use later.
- The callback wants to refer to the `Kinetic.Shape` object. Presumably there is some contract that describes what `this` refers to later (as evinced by the `this.getContext()` use), and it isn't the `Kinetic.Shape` object.
- Because `diagramImage` is a reference, and by the time the reference will be used, it will have been assigned the new `Kinetic.Shape`, it's kosher to use it for said purpose.

In principle, this is no different from the usual pattern of using a local variable to make the current this available in a callback, e.g.

```
var self = this;
$('myelement').click( function(){ self.hi = true; } );
```

It's just that here, the variable being made available for later isn't the current object, it's a member of said object.

Answer (score 0):

I think this post may help explain it - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Particularly the section on Associative Arrays.  The write explains that objects in javascript are also considered associative arrays.

So event though `diagramImage.strokeStyle` may not be explicitly defined, you can still reference `diagramImage['strokeStyle']`.

Does that help?